# How to show loading spinner in activity while this activity is loading(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android, loading, android-spinner

I have the following `MainActivity`

[image]

When I click its `GO TO SECOND ACTIVITY` button I go to `SecondActivity` but as in `SecondActivity` I have a very big zoomable image, the application stays on `MainActivity` for about 2, 3 seconds and then `SecondActivity` opens. Тo prevent the user from thinking that the `GO TO SECOND ACTIVITY` button doesn't work, I want to open `SecondActivity` as soon as the user presses `GO TO SECOND ACTIVITY` button and show а loading spinner in place of the image while the image is loading.

Here is my `SecondActivity.axml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageLoadingDemo.ScaleImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ,I create sample using ScaleImageView to display big zoomable image, and can open secondactivity immediately when I click Button,You can take a look: [Scaleimage](https://github.com/CherryBu/Scaleimage), and I am not sure this sentence:**show а loading spinner in place of the image while the image is loading**, why you want to show loading spinner, it presents a drop-down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first add a nuget pack like "urlimageviewhelper", that works fine for me
then use this code instead  common way

```
    Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(ImageViewSample, "ImageUrl", Resource.Drawable.Preloaing, IntNumber);
```

in the above code use 600000 for 10 minus cache Imgae

Resource.Drawable.Preloaing: it's preload image

So the activity loads fast and image show after loading

Comment: What do I have to put in the place of `ImageViewSample` , `"ImageUrl"` , `Resource.Drawable.Preloaing` , `IntNumber` ? My image size is `276 KB`

Comment: you should add Your ImageView instance
ImageUrl: Url Adress of Your Image

Comment: Resource.Drawable.Preloaing: add your defalut image to drawable folder and address it

Comment: intnumber: 600000

Comment: And `ImageViewSample`?

Comment: I said imageview instance: ImageView imageviewsample=FindViewById<ImageView>(resource....)

Comment: Trying to install the `urlimageviewhelper` package, I get the following error: `Package urlimageviewhelper 1.0.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package urlimageviewhelper 1.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)`

Comment: https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Get from this GitHub Link